# preg_replace_callback() walk around

Tags: php, preg-replace

Would like to do something like this:

```
$str = '<a>lalala</a>';
echo preg_replace('~<a>(.*)</a>~i','<a>'.str_replace('la','mi',"$1").'</a>',$str);
```

So it would return:

`<a>mimimi</a>`

But can't use `preg_replace_callback()` function. Any simple ideas?

Comment: How should `str_replace` know about the value of `$1`? Seriously, __how__?

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to walk around `preg_replace_callback()` ... as I said was a basic example... and would like to get answer on how to do it without that function (that doesn't seem to work on the hosting that I am using) ... maybe I didn't make it clear enough. Every time I am asking something, I'm trying to make it as clear as possible... and yes, I do understand that it doesn't work that way. The question is: what can I do about it the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to do specific operations in replacement:

```
$str = '<a>lalala</a>';
echo preg_replace_callback('~<a>(.*)</a>~i',function($matches){
  return '<a>'.str_replace('la','mi',$matches[1]).'</a>';
},$str);
```

Outputs:

```
<a>mimimi</a>
```

Or with `preg_match()`:

```
$str = '<a>lalala</a>';
if (preg_match('~<a>(.*)</a>~i', $str, $matches)) {
  $str = '<a>'.str_replace('la','mi',$matches[1]).'</a>';
};
echo $str;
```

Comment: yeah thank You for Your answer but that php seems not to recognizepreg_replace_callback - i totally don't know why... it's only some web hosting server (not even vps)... I tried to use it at first, but it simply says its not a recognized function... :-(

Comment: Why didn't you ask a question about that? Why you ask a question about a thing that is really not connected to your issue?

Comment: @FlashThunder Oh... I don't know why your hosting server disallow the use of this function, but the code above works as expected : https://eval.in/981905

Comment: @u_mulder I don't know... maybe I am assuming that people would understand that example more than saying something about callbacks... but good point. I really don't ask questions too often in here. Last question - 2 months ago, previous - 4 months ago. I rather answer than ask.

Comment: @Syscall your answer was correct, but that function doesn't seem to work in many hosting companies (had that problem like in 10) ... but ofc `+1` for that... as it would be correct if function would be supported.

Comment: `pcre` extension is a core extension and unless your php is 5.2 and older, it must be available. So, I suppose your doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh so it's `pcre` ... ok ... I am totally sure I am not doing anything wrong... but had that situation many times... From a developer point of view this is really annoying... everything works on testing dedicated server, and then it doesn't on clients server... that exact function (`preg_replace_callback()`) causes problems... maybe because I am using it in every parser.

Comment: @FlashThunder I've updated the answer with `preg_match()` alternative.

Comment: @FlashThunder Maybe your PHP Version does not support the use of anonymous function (>=5.3). [This workaround  should work in PHP >= 4.05](https://eval.in/981908)

Comment: @bobblebubble had that problem few times as well... and yes, fixed it exactly the same way, as you have shown.  But that wasn't the case... corporate servers got sometimes some weird restrictions... and in most cases in big companies there is no way to get any information about it. Would give few examples, but I don't think that the companies I am working for would like me to do so...

Comment: By the way... that's what you get when you have to work even during Easter... the smallest problems seem to be huge. Such a simple solution, that I am ashamed that I even asked about it.